# How to get location of UIView in modally presented viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am presenting a viewcontroller with a custom presentationStyle. The parent Controller is a UICollectionViewController. In my didSelectAtIndexPath method of the UICollectionViewController I am taking the UIImageView of the selected cell and animating it to the location of a UIView's frame within the viewcontroller that is modally presented.

How can I get the UIView's frame of the modally presented viewcontroller?

```
self.imageView!.frame = trophyOverlayVC.trophyImageLocationView!.frame
```

does not work.

It appears off the screen in most cases.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionHolderViewController: MainPageContentViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    [..insert other methods here..]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TrophyCollectionViewCell

        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.scrollEnabled = false // disable scrolling so view won't move
        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.userInteractionEnabled = false
        let innerOffset = collectionView.contentOffset as CGPoint // offset of content view due to scrolling
        let attributes = self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!
        let cellRect = attributes.frame // frame of cell in contentView

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x, cellRect.origin.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height)) //places image in location of collectionViewCell.
        imageView!.image = UIImage(named: placeHolderArray[indexPath.row]) //change.
        imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.addSubview(imageView!)


        self.placeHolderArray[indexPath.row] = ""
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

        var trophyOverlayVC = self.collectionViewController.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrophyOverlayVC") as TrophyOverlayViewController
        trophyOverlayVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
        self.presentViewController(trophyOverlayVC, animated: false, completion: self.presentViewController(trophyOverlayVC, animated: false, completion: { (value: Void) in UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.imageView!.frame = trophyOverlayVC.trophyImageLocationView!.frame
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
    }) })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to animate it immediately, do this inside the `presentViewController` completion block (where you're currently passing `nil`). At this point, all of the `frame`s will be set properly.

Also, this approach will only work if their superviews are placed identically in the coordinate system. Remember that a frame's `origin` (and a view's `center`) are coordinates *in relation to their superview*. If they're not the same, you'll need to use `UIView`'s `convertRect(_:toView:)` or `convertRect(_:fromView:)` to convert the rect to the appropriate view's coordinate system.

Comment: alrighty so I now have the animation occur in the completion block. This did not fix the problem, so I think I will need to use convertRect.

Comment: Would anyone be able to provide an example using the code I've posted?